# Pytorch version of numpy.histogram

Tags: python, pytorch

I want to convert the output label into a distribution and force the distribution into my desired values through KL divergence loss. Although I can do it through for loop or `numpy.histogram`, the gradient is lost and I have the following error:

```
RuntimeError: element 0 of tensors does not require grad and does not have a grad_fn
```

Is there an alternative of `numpy.histogram` in pytorch? Or any similar approach workable when doing `loss.backward()`?

Comment: Have you tried `torch.histc`? Check the [official documentation](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/torch.html#torch.histc).

Comment: @MohammadArvan It will do for uniform spacing binning. However, what is it possible to use custom binning like `numpy.histogram`?

Comment: Then you have to implement the algorithm yourself using the pytorch, the gradients cannot be calculated when you use numpy.

Comment: is there any suggestion on how the code should be implemented in pytorch?

Comment: What is the gradient of the loss with respect to the histograms? I wrote a few lines for calculating histogram with custom bin size, however, gradients still cannot calculated  since the histogram is not differentiable.